# Media Player is restarting the file when I re-enter the activity

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a music player app which consists of a "playlist" and a "now playing" activity.

The two activities are linked using a menu for navigation.

When I select a song from the playlist is plays as expected in the background - I can go to the playlist and browse other songs...

However when I then use the menu to return to the now playing activity, it restarts the media file instead of just resuming? Surely it would just continue playing?

The below logic is inside of the onCreate() method but I have a feeling I should add to the onResume() method too?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

--

```
    if (itemSelected || !mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){            //Gets media as normal     
        infoSetter();
        musicPlayer();
    } else if (!itemSelected && !mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {   //Sets defaults if activity is accessed without making a selection     
        defaultInfoSetter();
        defaultMusicPlayer();
    } else if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){        //TODO: Fix this part                           
        //???????????????
    }
```

Comment: If you want to have any media play outside of activity you should host your media player in a service. If you're only holding media player reference in an activity and don't stop/kill it when leaving said activity it's practically a leak.

Comment: The media player is working as expected - it is still playing music when I leave the activity(in the background). And when I re-enter the activity it even gets all the correct info/media file but then re-starts it from 0:00.

Comment: have you tested your app with "don't keep activities" option enabled?

Comment: No, but when I leave the activity using the "back button" (which is supposed to close the activity right?), it keeps playing music. And then when I re-enter it crashes the app.

Comment: You leak media player because you don't close it alongside activity. It might still play but you have no way to control it since activity was the only object holding reference to it. When you "re-enter" you spawn new media player instance and then media sessions clash (I can only assume since your code sample is very minimal).

Comment: Yes the media player and audio manager are created in this same activity.

So does that mean I should create a separate class for the media player containing all of the logic?

Comment: I suggest creating a foreground service and binding to it.